# Create a tree from JSON

Tags: javascript, tree

I am fairly new to Javascript, I've had some classes, but I am still learning about it and I was working on making a tree from a JSON. I looked at other answers over here, but I just can't seem to understand that reduce, recursion and jquery thingys. So I made my own functions.

But first, my JSON looks like this:

```
var data = [{
   "id": 51,
   "name": "root"
}, {
  "id": 54,
  "name": "app",
  "parentId": 53
}, {
  "id": 55,
  "name": "text.txt",
  "parentId": 54
}, {
 "id": 53,
 "name": "share",
 "parentId": 52
}, {
 "id": 52,
 "name": "local",
 "parentId": 51
}];
```

And these functions process the JSON object:

```
var treeNode = function(nodeId, name) {
    var children = [];

    this.nodeId = nodeId;
    this.name = name;
    this.parentNode = null;

    this.setParent = function(parentNode) {
       this.parentNode = parentNode;
    };
    this.addChild = function(node){
       children.push(node);
       node.setParent(this);
    };
};

var Tree = function() {
  this.nodes = [];
  this.findNodeById = function(nodeId) {
     for (var i=0; i<this.nodes.length; i++) {
        if (this.nodes[i].nodeId === nodeId) {
           return this.nodes[i];
        }
   }
   return null;
  };
  this.createNode = function(nodeId, name, parentNode) {
     var node = new treeNode(nodeId, name);
     if (parentNode) {
       parentNode.addChild(node);
     }
     this.nodes.push(node);
   }
};

function createTree(data) {

  var tree = new Tree();
  var temp = [];
  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var inputNode = data[i];
    var parentNode = inputNode.parentId ? tree.findNodeById(inputNode.parentId) : null;
    tree.createNode(inputNode.id, inputNode.name, parentNode);
  }
 return tree.nodes;
}
```

Then I call the function: createTree(data);

So after much debugging trying to make the functions and the like I finally realized that I may be making a mistake somewhere because right now the parents for nodes for 54 and 53 are not showing and I just can't wrap my head around what I am doing wrong and how can I fix it? Can somebody help me please?

Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks good in general. The problem is algorithmical.
It is directly related to the order of inserting nodes.

### Cause

You have an empty tree.
First, you insert node #51. Now, you have a tree with single node #51.
And then you try to insert node #54 with parentNode #53...which doesn't exist.

Here

```
var parentNode = inputNode.parentId ? tree.findNodeById(inputNode.parentId) : null;
```

you call `tree.findNodeById`, which iterates through your tree, cannot find node 53 (it is not in a tree yet), and returns `null`.

Thus, your second node gets `parentNode` set to `null`, instead of node #53.

### Solution

The basic idea is that you always need to ensure that for every node being inserted its parent node is already in the tree.

### How to achieve this?

The easiest solution for your input data which comes to my mind is to sort your array on `parentNode` in ascending order before inserting.
It will guarantee that you always insert child nodes after parent node, but it only works if nodes are numbered in **topological order**.
It means that `parentId` is always less than `id`. For instance, node 5 cannot have a parent with ID 7.

Here, it works properly for your input data:

```js
var data = [{
   "id": 51,
   "name": "root"
}, {
  "id": 54,
  "name": "app",
  "parentId": 53
}, {
  "id": 55,
  "name": "text.txt",
  "parentId": 54
}, {
 "id": 53,
 "name": "share",
 "parentId": 52
}, {
 "id": 52,
 "name": "local",
 "parentId": 51
}];


var treeNode = function(nodeId, name) {
    var children = [];

    this.nodeId = nodeId;
    this.name = name;
    this.parentNode = null;

    this.setParent = function(parentNode) {
       this.parentNode = parentNode;
    };
    this.addChild = function(node){
       children.push(node);
       node.setParent(this);
    };
};

var Tree = function() {
  this.nodes = [];
  this.findNodeById = function(nodeId) {
     for (var i=0; i<this.nodes.length; i++) {
        if (this.nodes[i].nodeId === nodeId) {
           return this.nodes[i];
        }
   }
   return null;
  };
  this.createNode = function(nodeId, name, parentNode) {
     var node = new treeNode(nodeId, name);
     if (parentNode) {
       parentNode.addChild(node);
     }
     this.nodes.push(node);
   }
};



function createTree(data) {
  // HERE, you sort your array by parentId ASC:
  data = data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.parentId - b.parentId;
  });

  var tree = new Tree();
  var temp = [];
  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var inputNode = data[i];
    var parentNode = inputNode.parentId ? tree.findNodeById(inputNode.parentId) : null;
    tree.createNode(inputNode.id, inputNode.name,  parentNode);
  }
 return tree.nodes;
}

console.log(createTree(data));
```

However, if your nodes are numbered randomly, then you will need to implement [**topological sorting**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) instead of simple sorting by `parentId`.

### P.S.

By the way, you may want to use object map instead of array in order to not iterate through it every time. It will give `O(n)` times improvement - `O(1)` instead of `O(n)`:

```
var Tree = function() {
  this.nodes = {};
  this.findNodeById = function(nodeId) {
     return nodes[nodeId];
  };
  this.createNode = function(nodeId, name, parentNode) {
     var node = new treeNode(nodeId, name);

     if (parentNode) {
       parentNode.addChild(node);
     }

     if (this.nodes[nodeId]) {
       throw new Error("There is already node with ID " + nodeId + " in the tree.");
     }

     this.nodes[nodeId] = node;
   }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I understand this part, essentially the children are being made before the parents right? But I think the parentIds and ids are arbitrary numbers, they are not always going to be a smaller.

Comment: Is there a way without any sorting?